# MySQL connection pools in Node.js (mysql2)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, connection-pooling, mysql2

I am struggling to find documentation that describes how so called "Connection Pools" work in Node.js applications, running with the mysql2 package from NPM. I only managed to find some short examples of it on their NPM page, but there is a lack of explanation of how it actually works.

I've got this code in my express app:

/main.js:

```
const db = require('./modules/databaseFunctions');

app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    const worlds = await db.getWorlds();
    res.render('test', { worlds: worlds });
});
```

/modules/databaseFunctions.js:

```
const db = require('./databaseConnection');

async function getWorlds() {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM worlds";
    const [rows] = await db.connection.query(sql);
    return rows;
}

exports.getWorlds = getWorlds;
```

/modules/databaseConnection.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

// Establish connection to database
const connection = mysql.createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    maxIdle: 10,
    idleTimeout: 60000,
    queueLimit: 0
});

exports.connection = connection;
```

So if we take a look at the "databaseConnection.js" file where I create a connection pool to the database, I have set it to a max limit of 10 connections in the pool. But what would happen if 50 users would be on my website and attempt to load `/test` page? Would only 10 of them go through and what happens to the others? And how would I manage a lot of users on the website overall? Any recommendations for queuelimits and connectionlimits?

What happens if only 2 users visit my site? Will there be 8 empty connections? I don't see how this is more beneficial for the performance in that case.

Is there any way to redirect users to another page if all connections are taken?

Can anyone explain how this all works? I am struggling to understand how it all works, how the limits work, will it create more connection pools if the first pool (10 connections) are taken?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection pooling is a technique that can help improve the performance of Node.js applications that need to make frequent database requests. Instead of opening a new connection for every request, connection pooling allows the application to reuse existing connections from a pool, which reduces the overhead of establishing new connections.

If more than the maximum number of connections in the pool (in this case, 10) are needed, the connection pool will queue the requests and process them as connections become available. By default, the queue is unlimited, so it can grow as needed.

If the maximum number of connections is not reached, the connection pool will maintain idle connections in the pool that can be reused for subsequent requests, which can help improve the application's performance.

If all connections in the pool are taken and a new request comes in, the connection pool will queue the request until a connection becomes available. If the queue limit is reached and a new request is made, an error will be thrown. To avoid this, you can increase the queue limit or connection limit of the pool.

Comment: So let's say I erase the queuelimit and it goes back to its default state (unlimited). And 11 people visit the `/test` link on my page. Will the 11th visitor see a blank screen, a loading screen? Or what will happen - do they need to refresh the page? And are the connections only in use while running the SQL query? Or until a user has CLOSED the page? My queries execute in milliseconds, but will they take up space in the queue as long as a user is looking at the page? Will the connection remain established even after the query executed?

Comment: If the queueLimit option is not set, the connection pool will queue all incoming requests until a connection becomes available. Therefore, if 11 visitors attempt to load the /test page and all 10 connections in the pool are already in use, the 11th visitor's request will be queued and will eventually be executed as soon as a connection becomes available. Connections in the pool are in use only while executing a query. Once a query is executed and the results are returned, the connection is returned to the pool and can be reused for subsequent requests.

Comment: Got it. How does it work if only 2 people open the page? Will it create a new connection for each user, up until a max limit of 10. Or will it open 10 at once? Also, isn't my code launching a new instance of the "databaseConnection.js" file each time the .getWorlds() function is called, making it launch a new pool each time? And I assume I never have to close any connections after being done? Basically... is my code correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: It doesnt really depend on how many users are visiting your page, like one connection per user, more how many queries those users are requiring to be executed. You are not creating a new pool of connections each time you query the pool as you are querying an export of a pool, not instantiating a new pool. Your code lgtm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Just learning how to connect to MySQL with my Node.js app and it seems pools are the way to go. I will remove the queuelimit I suppose and perhaps bump the connection/maxidle limit to 20 to make sure it works for my amount of visitors.

Comment: Of course! I would say keeping a set limit is always a good idea, especially if you may experience large traffic since most sql servers have a preset connection limit which you can obviously alter, but still its good to have a set limit.

Comment: What are the defaults of `initialSize`, `maxIdle`, etc.? The docs are not clear about that: https://sidorares.github.io/node-mysql2/docs/examples/connections/create-pool. And also doesn't share any good production best-pratices.

Comment: To answer myself, when looking into the source itself (since it's missing from the docs). : It seems like that `maxIdle` is by default equal to` connectionLimit` (so no need to set it manually, unless you really want). `connectionLimit` is by default just 10, this you might want to increase to 20 or higher indeed. And there is no `initialSize` anymore ;(.